# Sail - Initiate Xdebug session from command line

Tags: laravel, xdebug, laravel-sail, laravel-9

So the last version of Sails makes it very easy to use Xdebug. Basically just had to define `SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE` in the `.env` file, configure path mapping in PhpStorm, activate listening and all was set - it works perfectly from the browser.

Now, how should I go if I want Xdebug to activate when I'm using the command line? Like when using artisan commands for seeding, or even better when using custom artisan commands created to run scripts to update some data... I can't find any arguments to add to my `sail artisan myOwnCommand` that would tell Xdebug it has to activate.

I'm working on Windows 11 with WSL2.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Prepending them with `XDEBUG_SESSION=jeremy` would likely do it. You can also export that as an environment variable. Use Xdebug's `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10` settings in a PHP ini file, to verify that Xdebug is trying to do the right thing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can use command `debug` to run with Xdebug (ex. `sail debug myOwnCommand`).
Here is documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#xdebug-cli-usage

Comment: I'm using it already ^^ anyway, since it's now the good answer I'm validating it.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Derick's suggestion, I found out a solution. Prepending a `sail` call with anything wouldn't help, since sail calls scripts in the docker container, and your environment variable wouldn't be set there. But since it was just about setting an environment variable, it can be easily done in `docker-compose` file.

I just had to add `PHP_IDE_CONFIG: 'serverName=0.0.0.0'` in the `environment` section of my Laravel service. Of course replace `0.0.0.0` with your own server name. Then, instead of running `sail artisan test` or `sail artisan my:command` you replace `artisan` with `debug`, as stated [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#xdebug-cli-usage).

Comment: The IDE key value doesn't (and shouldn't) matter for PhpStorm.

Comment: - 1 PHP_IDE_CONFIG: 'serverName=0.0.0.0'  

- 2  Needed to comment  SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=<172.21.0.1>"  in .env file,  despite link docs guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The 'replace with your own server name' confused me. What you have to do apparently is:

- PhpStorm > Settings > PHP > Servers > Add server
- Name: "Docker" (whatever you want really)
- Host: 0.0.0.0
- Port: 80
- Debugger: Xdebug
- [X] User path mappings
- Map the root to `/var/www/html`

Then, in `docker-compose.yml`, add this node, with whatever name you chose earlier:

```yaml
services:
    laravel.test:
        environment:
            PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=Docker
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! omg saved my day, i was 6 hours trying to figure this sh*t out, we need xdebug revolution for setting it up